# Is there a way to take data from my csv file and put it on my website

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web

Essentially using Python3 I've scraped: Movie Title, URL, Genre, Source, and the image Banner from 2 streaming websites into a CSV file. I want to take all the information I've scraped and put it up on my website.

Pretty much I want to make it look exactly the same as it would on the streaming website. I'm rather new to programming so any recommendations on videos to watch to help with this would be appreciated.

As there's 150 videos so I don't want to have to create 150 different containers and manually add them the necessary info. So I'm wondering how I can speed up this process.

All recommendations welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If your using flask try this.
Just read the data from the file into a variable and then pass it into your html file.

```
# import the csv module
# there is no need to install the module as it comes with python
import csv


# define your route
@app.route('/my-route')
def my_route():
    path = r'C:\MyPath\csv.file' # path to your csv file

    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        csv_data = []
        for row in reader:
            csv_data.append(row)

    # add the following line if you want to remove the csv names from your data
    # csv_data.pop(0)

    print(csv_data)

    return render_template('index.html', csv_data=csv_data)
```